Get return type of a function definition without specifying its arguments
How can I get return type of a function definition.
I need to get the type without knowing anything about the argument list.
I can’t use std::invoke_result because in this way  I need to know list of arguments.

This might be an XY problem. Can you share some more info about the actual case where it is needed ?

You can use decltype.

A function can be overloaded. W/o arguments, you can't know which of overloaded function to choose.

if you dont know the argument list, you dont know the function declaration.

C++ code can have overloads of a function (different argument types) and the return type can depend on which overload is selected. So TLDR: This cannot be done in general. So maybe you can explain better WHAT you want to do

How are you getting the function? Is its type a template parameter? (That's the most likely scenario I could think of where you could have something without knowing its type.)

in my case the function returns a lambda whose return type is determined depending on the type of the function that was passed to the enclosing function as a template parameter. also in my case there can be no function overloads

Simplest way to determine return type of function without repeating the function's parameter types

With traits to extract information from signature type:
// traits to extract information from signature
template <typename Sig> struct function_traits;

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<Ret(Args...)>
{
    using return_type = Ret;
    constexpr std::size_t arity = sizeof...(Args);
    // ...
};

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<Ret(Args..., ...)> // C-ellipsis
{
    using return_type = Ret;
    constexpr std::size_t arity = sizeof...(Args);
    // ...
};

template <typename PtrSig>
struct function_traits<PtrSig*> : function_traits<PtrSig> {};

If there are no other overloads, you might then do:
char foo(int, float);

using RetType = function_trait<decltype(&foo)>::return_type;

